# Are DBSet<> object's ids set when assigning one to the other?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities with relation one-many in DB and corresponding classes generated by reverse engineering the database.

```
public partial class Assets
{
    public int AssetsId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Persons Person { get; set; }
}

public partial class Persons
{
    public Persons()
    {
        Assets = new HashSet<Assets>();
    }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

When I assign one entity to the other do the corresponding ID's are set automatically (i am curious if they are set before SaveChanges is called, so i could use it without committing all current changes).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Context c = new Context();

    var a = new Assets();
    a.AssetsId = 1;
    var p = new Persons();
    p.PersonId = 2;

    c.Add(a);
    c.Add(p);

    a.Person = p;    //does it set a.PersonId = 2
    p.Assets.Add(a); //does it set a.PersonId = 2
        
    c.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The answer: Yes, they do.

Comment: Avoid directly manipulating IDs. Also, keys are typically auto-generated.

Comment: No foreign key changes are done until SaveChanges of the context is performed. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: If that's how it behaves, changing it would be dangerous. Why do you need the ids? Your example is contrived because you are manually specifying primary keys.

Comment: Yes it is contrived. I had to simplify my project. The idea is that one object is retrieved from the context and one is new. Then I need to know if id's are updated before SaveChanges is called or do i need to call SaveChanges during my procedure.

Answer (score 0):

(You can just check the answer to your question in the debugger or with a simple test using your provided code.)

> When I assign one entity to the other do the corresponding ID's are set automatically [before SaveChanges is called later?]

No, they are not. The reason is, that your navigation properties here are really just POCO properties (meaning simple .NET properties). The `Assets.Persons` property is really just a property of type `Persons` and the `Persons.Assets` property contains really just the `HashSet<Assets>` instance that you assigned in the constructor. There is no magic here.

The IDs are being synchronized automatically during change tracking, which happens for example when `SaveChanges()` is called, but can also manually be triggered by calling `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`.

---

As a side note, be aware that you should not set IDs in your code explicitly, if you are using identity/auto increment columns for primary keys, because this can lead to exceptions when saving (depending on the database server being used), due to EF Core trying to insert the explicitly assigned ID to the identity/auto increment column (e.g. this is not allowed by default for SQL Server).